# java.security.KeyStoreException when running my app with docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, docker-compose, keystore

I have my spring boot project connected to mysql and cassandra db.
When I run it locally with spring boot, all went ok. I use docker-compose to run these three services.
For three weeks, my application runs without problems. But now an error occure :
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Key protection  algorithm not found: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Encrypt Private Key failed: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recently got the same problem and found the following discussion saying it is a bug that happens on JDK 8u292 but not on 8u282:
https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/941

In my case, I switched back to 8u282 and the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you Philip. I resolve this problem by changing openJdk:8 to openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9 in my Dockerfile.

Comment: in my case i set the file java.security of the jvm. I added at the end of this file :  keystore.pkcs12.keyProtectionAlgorithm=PBEWithHmacSHA256AndAES_256

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in openjdk 8u292. Update openjdk to 8u302 or higher version.

8u292 -> 8u312 I resolve this problem.

```
hanwei@hanweideMacBook-Air tt]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
hanwei@hanweideMacBook-Air tt]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.58.0.13-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 1.8.0_312-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.58.0.13-CA-macos-aarch64) (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8266261

> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8242565

Comment: Are we sure that this is only due to variation of versions of java

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me also during SpringBoot App Launch. This is due to openjdk version 1.8.0_292 and switching to Standard HotSpot Java version 1.8.0_202 resolved the problem. Probably bug in OpenJdk.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task :app:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest FAILED
Cause: unrecognized algorithm name: PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
```

**2024**: I had this problem on MacOS Sonoma with Android Studio Hedgehog.
Symptom: ./android/debug.keystore.lock exists but no debug.keystore anywhere on my filesystem to be found. Deleting the .android directory recreates it, but no debug.keystore to be found after, with the same problems again. To solve it create the keystore manually:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I think there is some Apple system holding an outdated version of this file. Its not Keychain :-(